# facebook light box jquery pop up with delay of 30 seconds in blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, blogger

I have a facebook light box pop up on my blogger blog which comes immediately when a user opens my website but i want it to pop up after some seconds delay after page load (30 seconds or 1 minute ) . 
Here is my jquery code of pop up .

```
    <!-- popup plug-in snippet  -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
//grab user's browser info and calculates/saves first visit
jQuery.cookie = function (key, value, options) { if (arguments.length > 1 && String(value) !== "[object Object]") { options = jQuery.extend({}, options); if (value === null || value === undefined) { options.expires = -1; }
if (typeof options.expires === 'number') { var days = options.expires,  t = options.expires = new Date();  t.setDate(t.getDate() + days); } value = String(value); return (document.cookie = [encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value), options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '', options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '', options.secure ? '; secure' : ''].join('')); }
options = value || {}; var result, decode = options.raw ? function (s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent; return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1]) : null; };
// the pop up actions
//$(function ($) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if ($.cookie('popup_fb') != 'yes') {
    $('#fb-back').delay(2000).fadeIn("slow"); // options slow or fast
    $('#fb-close, #fb-exit').click(function () {
      $('#fb-back').stop().fadeOut("slow"); // options slow or fast
    });
 }
//initiate popup function by setting up the cookie expiring time
$.cookie('popup_fb', 'yes', { path: '/', expires: 0 });
});
//]]>
```

please help anyone .

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery.lightbox("www.mydomain.com/popup.html?lightbox[width]=650&lightbox[height]=480");
      },10000);
});  Just you will try this code this is just example

Comment: Refer this--->https://forum.jquery.com/topic/delay-of-popup-on-page-load

Comment: I am not so good at coding ?

Comment: Can you give me some solution to modify in my code and my work can be done ?

Comment: i can't paste my ans in comment box so kindly contact cfprabhu@yahoo.com?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.cookie = function (key, value, options) { if (arguments.length > 1 && String(value) !== "[object Object]") { options = jQuery.extend({}, options); if (value === null || value === undefined) { options.expires = -1; }
if (typeof options.expires === 'number') { var days = options.expires,  t = options.expires = new Date();  t.setDate(t.getDate() + days); } value = String(value); return (document.cookie = [encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value), options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '', options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '', options.secure ? '; secure' : ''].join('')); }
options = value || {}; var result, decode = options.raw ? function (s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent; return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1]) : null; };
$(function ($) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if ($.cookie('popup_fb') != 'yes') {
    $('#fb-back').delay(30000).fadeIn("slow"); // options slow or fast
    $('#fb-close, #fb-exit').click(function () {
      $('#fb-back').stop().fadeOut("slow"); // options slow or fast
    });
 }
$.cookie('popup_fb', 'yes', { path: '/', expires: 0 });
});
//]]>
</script>
```